# Appending/Prepending selecting with siblings() not working with HTML tag elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<span class="apparatus type-substantive">
<span class="reading HQ1">I there’s the </span>
<span class="reading TTQ1 BQ1">ay, there's the </span>
<span class="reading HQ2 BQ2 BF BE HaF MW GBE HJ DB4 BR PE TW TS TTQ2 TTF RSM"> that is the </span>
</span>
```

And I want to inject "<" and ">" before and after the one with class HQ2 (third span), and { and } before and after the one which has class HQ1 (first span), so I've done this:

```
$('span.HQ2').prepend('<span class="pended">&lt;</span>').append('<span class="pended">&t;</span>').siblings('.HQ1').prepend('<span class="pended">&#123;</span>').append('<span class="pended">&#125;</span>').css('color','#217b26');
```

The problem is that the result is not the one I expected, because the second append and prepend are not working, these only work if I remove the span tags and leave the "{" and "}" alone. The .css() works as expected, so the selection is done properly with .siblings(). I think the problem may rely in the result that .siblings() is giving me, maybe it does not accept prepending and appending HTML tags or something. I don't know...

Could you enlighten me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please fix the code first, look at `><<`. You should use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Done, but the result is the same.

Comment: `.prepend()` and `.append()` add child elements. Perhaps you want to use `.before()` and `.after()`.

Comment: @JohnS that works! Thank you very much. But it would be cool to know why it's not working with .append() and .prepend()

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vukn9at/) with `prepend()` & `.append()`, and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0fq6a0L/) with `.before()` & `.after()`. The results looks the same for me (using Firefox). (I did fix the typo where you had "&t;" instead of "&gt;".)

Comment: @JohnS I see... thanks. There may be something wrong in my full code which is spoiling this... I will have to check it better.

Answer (score 0):

try '\' before greater than and less than marks. this will ensure they are interpreted as text:

```js
$('span.HQ2').prepend('<span class="pended">\<</span>').append('<span class="pended">\></span>').siblings('.HQ1').prepend('<span class="pended">&#123;</span>').append('<span class="pended">&#125;</span>').css('color', '#217b26');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="apparatus type-substantive">
<span class="reading HQ1">I there’s the </span>

<span class="reading TTQ1 BQ1">ay, there's the </span>

<span class="reading HQ2 BQ2 BF BE HaF MW GBE HJ DB4 BR PE TW TS TTQ2 TTF RSM"> that is the </span>
</span>
```

Comment: That's not working in my code... maybe because I've simplified the thing a little bit in my question. Using .before() and .after() as @JohnS suggested works. Thank you very much anyway ;)

Comment: no problem. i think backslash is a good alternative though, if you are tired of searching for html key codes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Today I've found out why this wasn't working... apparently I forgot I had a piece of jquery later in the same code preventing me from doing this... I've been fooled by my own code. :/
Thank you all, anyways.